# Ruby/HAML no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby, haml

I have a database command that returns this:

```
[{:score=>66.54}]
```

to the @score object

In HAML I am trying to get that score value, and I am calling it like this:
`Score: #{@score}`, but it is just showing up like this: `[{:score=>66.54}]`

And when I try this `#{@score[:score]}` it says `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`.

How do I get the proper result?

Comment: `[{:score=>66.54}]` is an array with one element that is a Hash so `@score[0][:score]` is what you want. Or better, figure out why `@score` is an array in the first place and fix that.

Comment: That worked and fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because its an array I had to do this to get the result.

```
@score[0][:score]
```

fixed it

Comment: What is the "because" for?